# trigger before insert mysql 5.7 Error 1064 4200 on line 7

Tags: mysql

```
USE FacturationDB;

CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_User_DateHeureEnregistre
    BEFORE INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (DATE(NEW.DateHeureEnregistre)) != (CURDATE())
            THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Erreur date et heure enregistrement sur table Users';
            END IF;
        END;

CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_Article_DateHeureEnregistre
    BEFORE INSERT ON ARTICLES FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (DATE(NEW.DateHeureEnregistre)) != (CURDATE())
        THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Erreur date et heure enregistrement sur table Articles';
            END IF;
        END;
```

Comment: Did you set the delimiter?

Comment: Thank you so much. Delimiters were compulsory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE FacturationDB;

DELIMITER $$ /*Added Delimiter*/

CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_User_DateHeureEnregistre
    BEFORE INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (DATE(NEW.DateHeureEnregistre)) != (CURDATE())
            THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Erreur date et heure enregistrement sur table Users';
            END IF;
        END;
$$ /*Added Delimiter*/

CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_Article_DateHeureEnregistre
    BEFORE INSERT ON ARTICLES FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (DATE(NEW.DateHeureEnregistre)) != (CURDATE())
        THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Erreur date et heure enregistrement sur table Articles';
            END IF;
        END;
$$/*Added Delimiter*/
DELIMITER ; /*Reset ; Delimiter*/